# Add class to another div

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

Anyone could please tell me what am I doing wrong with this?

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/teoteo/rxggter7/

HTML

```
<div id="name">
    <a href="#">LINK</a>
</div>
<div id="year">
    <p>YEAR</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#year {
  color: #000;
}

.year-active {
  color: red;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#name').hover(function () {
        $('#year').addClass('year-active');
    }, function () {
        $('#year').removeClass('year-active');
    });
});
```

Comment: You have to include jquery library: http://jsfiddle.net/rxggter7/2/

Comment: You're not referencing jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add jQuery library located on the subnav (left side) under Frameworks & Extensions. Try jQuery 1.11.0, your code works!